# Run Bash script when laptop is locked

Tags: bash, performance, shell

I hope you're all doing fine.

I'm starting to use/learn Bash and I would like to know if it's possible to run a script at startup that detects when the laptop goes to sleep and then execute a series of commands.

Would it be too much memory consuming to have it running constantly? I guess it would behave just like a daemon.

Thank you in advance for any help and sorry for the noob question! I've been googling quite a lot but cannot really find a clear example of this. Only recommendations for apps, and I would like to build it myself (with your help, if possible :-)

Best regards,

**iPod.**

Comment: define "goes to sleep"

Comment: @jhnc sure thing sir, and sorry for the vague reference, as I am honestly not quite aware which is which. When I close my laptop lid, after a while, the screen is locked and I have to enter a password. Also, when the laptop suspends after a long period, I also need to enter my password.
In those two cases, I would like to a script to be run in order to arrange all my personal documents in a specific folder. Like a cleanup script.
Thanks for your reply and I hope you are having a nice weekend!

Comment: what OS? (Windows? Linux? Something else?) If linux, what distribution? If similar to Ubuntu, see for example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts

Comment: @jhnc; I'm running OSX El Capitan with Bash 3.2.57(1)-release.
Thanks for the link though, it's quite informative as to how laptop lid events work.

Comment: Apparently macos doesn't directly support triggering off sleep/wake. There are some third-party options that may work: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27036 https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/366685